# cross compiling qt for windows with opengl

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, cross-compiling, angle

I'm trying to compile QT-5.13.1 on ubunt 18.04 for windows with -opengl dynamic and -angle flags during configuration.

I can not get rid of the error

```
"ERROR: Feature 'angle' was enabled, but the pre-condition '! Features.opengl-desktop && features.dxguid && tests.fxc && (features.direct3d9 || (config.winrt && features.direct3d11 && libs.d3dcompiler)) 'failed. "
```

And

```
"ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!
You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL [_ES2],
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL [_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL [_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform. "
```

Help. how to do it?

Comment: It seems that you are trying to compile Qt for windows with linux libraries. Do you think that makes sense? Well, no. You should point to the manual you are using as the steps you have followed. A simpler option is to use MXE. https://mxe.cc/

Comment: @eyllanesc, Should I assemble angle for windows and add it to $PATH?